# How to display a grid of images that have different aspect ratios?

Tags: layout, image

If I have a grid of images, let's say political cartoons, that have differing aspect ratios and cannot be cropped, how can I display them in a grid or even linear fashion?

This is for a newspaper website, I have hundreds of political cartoons that cannot be cropped to a consistent aspect ratio due to content. I can display them linearly, top to bottom, but I would rather have a grid of some sort.

New cartoons will be added regularly, so the whole thing needs to be flexible.

Thoughts?

Comment: This is kinda broad, what are you trying to achieve? A poster, a page for a magazine, a webpage ? An image with at least rectangles of those images/aspect ratios would help. Will you continue adding images and the grid should be responsive and adapt or it's a fixed number? For now I am voting to close as **too broad**.

Comment: This depends allot on your requirements as mentioned by Alin. Is it required that the whole image stays visible? Otherwise zoom-copping might be useful. If the page needs quick navigation an asymmetrical look might not be a good option. You should write down some requirements ;)

Comment: Do you need to keep the timeline of the cartoons (i.e. the newest first) or can they be placed at random order?

Comment: Timeline is important.

Answer (score 5):

You have at least two options.

1. To create an optimal grid based on the available space,  like a mason fitting stones in a wall, you can use a [JS library designed for that purpose](https://masonry.desandro.com).
2. For a more symmetrical look, you can use a grid of identical background containers. This technique is commonly used to showcase logos -- [see this example](https://bynick.deviantart.com/art/Winter-Logo-Showcase-294664016).

   Create a grid of, let's say, four rows x four columns of white containers, each 300 x 300 pixels. These would serve as the 'canvases' for your images, which you would resize (maintaining the ratios) and insert appropriately.